# Oracle Instant Client setup for deployment

Tags: oracle

I need a solution to deploy the **Oracle Instant Client** on User's PC's (on or more) .Please suggest some way which I can do to make a Setup from what Oracle provides.

Basically the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/oci/instantclient/index.html) is a [ZIP file](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/oci/instantclient/htdocs/winsoft.html) (instantclient-basic-win32-11.1.0.7.0.zip (46,734,555 bytes)  you can extract to a folder on the User's  PC and then set:

- *1 x System Variable Path.*
- *3 x Environmental Variable.*

And your application can connect to oracle via the oci.dll.

Can I make a setup and include all these file and then the setup should set the :

- 1 x System Variable Path.
- 3 x  Environmental Variable.

I would host the setup on a intranet web server and the user will download the oracle client installer the installer would do its job.

Is this possible or feasible?

My other concerns would be would the setup run for a user (domain)?

Any suggestions welcome.

I could do this in WiX.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The tags aren't there to be a repeat of the subject, please keep the appropriate re-tagged version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is feasible.  I have seen this done at a former client of mine.

Suggestions:

1. Don't put tnsnames.ora on a
   network share.  This will break
   things in weird ways.  Use a name
   server instead.  You can use
   Oracle's or bind.  Bind is much more
   reliable.
2. Add something into your install
   so you can track how many people and
   who installs it.  This will help
   with later support.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the sort of thing that could just be done with a DOS batch file.